# GetAuthorizationGroups works with administrator user only

Tags: c#, web, permissions, active-directory

My website (with Windows authentificatication) in Intranet uses some DLL that checks current user permissions in Active Directory. It uses method GetAuthorizationGroups and works pefectly. The DLL was compiled about 10 years ago in VS 2005. Now I need to do some changes in its code (not connected to Active Directory). I opened the source code in VS 2012, framework 3.5 ,compiled it and copied to the server of the web site. Now an user that does not belong to Administrators group of this server gets error:
 **While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred**
There is n**o error with old version of DLL or when an user is administrato**r.
Below is the code I use:

PrincipalContext ctx =
 new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName,adusername, adpassword);
UserPrincipal user =
   UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userID);
PrincipalSearchResult groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

The server works under Windows Server 2012.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are compiling only this project in net framework 3.5, I suggest compile the entire solution in .net framework 3.5 and deploy everything together. Test it in a development environment only.

Comment: Also the web site was recompiled in 3.5. It didn't help.

Comment: A user that doesn't belong to administrator group gets error but I assume that users belong to administrator group works fine. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I wrote this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me which I've compiled in .net 3.5 and replaced userID with adusername, try by passing IdentityType  as a parameter (as shown below).

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName,
adusername, adpassword);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, adusername);
PrincipalSearchResult groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I got the same result:
While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred

Comment: Sorry, I did not reproduced exactly your code. Now  I got an error on
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userID);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the context this is running as (machine account if the app pool is Network Service) to the Windows Authorization Access Group in AD. This grants the requestor read access to the relevant attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should call to AD administrator to add an account to Windows Authorization Access Group. What is machine account? I tried to run the web site under different application pools. Particularly under pool that runs under a domain user that is an administrator in this machine. Is it sufficient if I'll add it to Windows Authorization Access Group?

Comment: The machine account is the computer's AD account - it is the same as the hostname of the machine. If the app pool runs as Network Service, your AD admin should add the computer account to the group. Otherwise, add the domain account the app pool is running as to the group.

Comment: Thank you, @brian-desmond, I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: I checked your suggestion but it also failed. The domain account of the app pool was added to  Windows Authorization Access Group but I get the same error: While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred (if user is not admin of the web site).